# How to connect to metamask from web app on mobile devices and trigger a smart contract call?

Tags: solidity, web3js, metamask

**Hi Dear Friends.**
I have only been able to find a way to use metamask in my page on desktop.
How to I make it work on mobile (iOS/android) and make a contract transaction .

take a look here:
https://docs.metamask.io/guide/mobile-best-practices.html#the-provider-window-ethereum

Without using web3modal and walletconnect is possible accomplish that with deeplink and metamask original code ?
Thanks a lot guys , i'm stuck on that , because i use angular is really hard to find a good solution .

Answer (score 0):

please check these links for android os:

```
https://medium.com/@nschapeler/an-introduction-to-ethereum-development-on-android-using-web3j-and-infura-763940719997
https://github.com/wise4rmgod/Web3Js-Android
```

And these for IOS:

```
https://medium.com/mercuryprotocol/introducing-web3-swift-for-ethereum-ios-development-1e02212b662b
https://github.com/Boilertalk/Web3.swift
```

Comment: I work on angular.js  web development not java sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use MetaMask DApp Browser. MetaMask is a java script enabled extension that's why You need an app to support javascript extensions. But in MetaMask mobile app DApp browser metamsk is hosted on window.ethereum you can you that DApp browser. Other then metamask you can also use trust wallet Dapp Browser for your smart contracts if deployed on mainnet.

Comment: so if i put regular metamsk code and with deeplink send the user to Metamask Browser You Think i can make transaction (trigger a smart contract function a let person approve with it metamask mobile wallet ?

Comment: yes it will work. I have done many times Metamask browser is inbuilt in metamask wallet.